# How to access iframe's javascript objects from parent page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to access iframe's javascript objects from javascript of parent page?

Comment: That depends on whether the iframe is from the same domain or not. If yes, then yes, if no, then no.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this. I assume your iFrame's id is `"targetFrame"` and the object you want to call is `targetObject` and also they are same domain. If they are not same domain I think it is not possible.:

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetObject
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that, you have to have in same domain in order to access child `window` object

Answer (score 5):

If the iframe src is not in the same origin/domain as the parent you'd have restrictions

because of the same-origin-policy (security policy) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

The policy is planned to block accessing private data such as CSRF tokens and other Private data stored in the frame, for example if you build an html page with an iframe of bank.com
then when people get into your site if they are logged into bank.com their private data will be stored in the iframe for that reason same-origin-policy will block different origins from accessing eachother's data through iframes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the objects of child iframe using the parent's window object.

```
alert( window.frames[0].variable_name );
```

It will show the value of variable, variable_name, from the first iFrame. The index of frames list can be used to access the values of variables across frames.

Comment: ES6/ES2015 update: this only works if `variable_name` was declared as `var variable_name;`, not as `let variable_name;`.  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let): "`let`, unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object."